# Search for nodes in Neo4j with schema index

Tags: indexing, neo4j, lucene

I have a graph that has only Schema indexes and not legacy indexes as Neo4j documentation recommends. I want to search for nodes like in [this](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-search.html) example described under the legacy indexing section (exact match, start queries etc). I am wondering if this is possible with schema indexes and if schema indexes use lucene underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today schema indexes just support exact matches, e.g.

```
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.name='abc'
```

or `IN` operators

```
MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.name in ['abc','def']
```

Future releases might have support for wildcards as well.

Comment: any idea when is it scheduled?

Comment: no guarantee here, but leading or trailing wildcards might come in 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

you can use wildcards as well in that case the query would be

MATCH (b:book) WHERE b.title=~"F.*" RETURN b;